# When can I remove convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary helper function?

Tags: ios, swift

When I migrated to **Swift 4.2** last year, Swift 4.2 migrator added a helper function in some of my controllers:

```
// Helper function inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
fileprivate func convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary(_ input: [String: Any]) -> [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any] {
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map { key, value in (UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey(rawValue: key), value)})
}
```

When is it safe to remove?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably, some function in that file (or in a prior version of the file) calls this `UIApplication` method:

```
func open(_ url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

Prior to iOS 12, the method had a different signature:

```
func open(_ url: URL, options: [String : Any] = [:], completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

When Xcode 10 migrated your project, it added the `convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary` function and inserted a call to that function in each call to the `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` method to translate the options dictionary.

If you update each call to the `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` method to use the `UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey` constants, you can remove the calls to `convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary` and remove the function entirely.

Comment: I see. It's indeed because I have this `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)`.

Comment: Then you can safely replace it with: `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)` and remove the function